# Linux: Autorun : "Run file from USB when usb is inserted "

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, usb

I'm trying to figure out that if windows can run a program in a usb when it is inserted then why not Linux or platforms?

In windows,
      we use Autorun /vb script to execute the autorun USB tasks.

```
[AutoRun]
OPEN=File.EXE
ICON=Path/icon.ico
ACTION=Start my application
LABEL=My Drive
```

and Saved as Autorun.inf

This will automatically start the required program to run while the usb is inserted.

Likewise, For Linux  **Bash**/any language  has anything like that?
Can run a file from usb automatically when it is inserted.

```
#!/bin/bash
touch myfile.txt
echo "File created Successfully"
```

Comment: so,what you trying to say is it  little bit different/difficult but its possible ,right?

Comment: When usb mass storage is inserted only block devices appear in Linux. All other actions including automount depend on installed software, distro defaults, user's configuration etc. Many users aren't happy if system execute anything from usb storage automatically.

Answer (score 1):

By default scripts called `autorun.sh` on any drives root directory will be automatically executed at least on Ubuntu Desktop.

However be aware that you need to be able to set execution permissions on the file. Otherwise the it will fail stating you lack permissions.
So for example on a FAT32 drive this will not work.

Comment: This is part of [the Desktop Application Autostart Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/latest/ar01s03.html).